# Is there a monitoring system for health-checking a Telegram bot?

Tags: monitoring, telegram-bot, health-check

I've searched for an out-of-the-box solution to monitor a **Telegram bot**, but it resulted in monitoring systems just sending the alerts **via** Telegram.
However, my use case is different: I want to monitor a bot itself and check periodically whether it responds to messages.
Are there any monitoring solutions supporting this feature?
(Although one can write another bot to do the job, I'm seeking an out-of-the-box (preferably free) solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! It seemed there was no such monitoring system.
I've developed one for those like me seeking a bot to monitor their bot health! Feel free to use it.
[BotMon GitHub repo](https://github.com/emranbm/botmon/tree/master)
[BotMon Telegram bot](https://t.me/thebotmon_bot)